# how to make an unknown level nested list and then get combinations of it as separated lists

Tags: python, combinations, nested-lists

I want to get all different combinations of a nested list which level is unknown.

I looked for the solution but all similar problems are not exactly what I'm looking for.

Consider that the levels may be very depth than this e.g. for 5 or 6 level inner.

The main problem is implementing a backpointer for CKY algorithm to get all possible syntactic trees, which is a nested list with REALLY unknown levels!!!

I have a backpointer as this:

```
backpointer = {
    (0, 2, 'NP'): {
        (1, 'AD', 'NP')
    }, 
    (1, 3, 'X1'): {
        (2, 'NP', 'PA')
    }, 
    (1, 3, 'NP'): {
        (2, 'NP', 'NP')
    }, (0, 3, 'X1'): {
        (2, 'NP', 'PA'), 
        (1, 'DT', 'NP')
    }, 
    (2, 4, 'X2'): {
        (3, 'PA', 'VP')
    }, 
    (1, 4, 'S'): {
        (2, 'NP', 'X2'), 
        (3, 'X1', 'VP')
    }, 
    (0, 4, 'S'): {
        (2, 'NP', 'X2'), 
        (3, 'X1', 'VP')
    }
}
```

which I backward from (0, 4, 'S') by considering all possible ways.

My current output is like this which is not classified.:

```
[
    (0, 4, 'S'), (0, 3, 'X1'), (0, 2, 'NP'), (0, 1, 'AD'), (1, 2, 'NP'), (2, 3, 'PA'), 
    (0, 1, 'DT'), (1, 3, 'NP'), (1, 2, 'NP'), (2, 3, 'NP'), (3, 4, 'VP'), (0, 2, 'NP'), 
    (0, 1, 'AD'), (1, 2, 'NP'), (2, 4, 'X2'), (2, 3, 'PA'), (3, 4, 'VP')
]
```

And I am trying to get it as a nested list like below to make it classified

```
[
    (0, 4, 'S'), 
    [
        (0, 2, 'NP'), (2, 4, 'X2'), (0, 1, 'AD'), (1, 2, 'NP'), (2, 3, 'PA'), (3, 4, 'VP')
    ], 
    [
        (0, 3, 'X1'), 
        (3, 4, 'VP'), 
        [
            (0, 2, 'NP'), (2, 3, 'PA'), (0, 1, 'AD'), (1, 2, 'NP')
        ], 
        [
            (0, 1, 'AD'), (1, 3, 'NP'), (1, 2, 'NP'), (2, 3, 'NP')
        ]
    ]
]
```

and then show it to user as some lists for each possible unique tree.

```
[
    (0, 4, 'S'), (0, 2, 'NP'), (2, 4, 'X2'), (0, 1, 'AD'), 
    (1, 2, 'NP'), (2, 3, 'PA'), (3, 4, 'VP')
]

[
    (0, 4, 'S'), (0, 3, 'X1'),(3, 4, 'VP'), (0, 2, 'NP'), 
    (2, 3, 'PA'), (0, 1, 'AD'), (1, 2, 'NP')
]

[
    (0, 4, 'S'), (0, 3, 'X1'),(3, 4, 'VP'), (0, 1, 'AD'), 
    (1, 3, 'NP'), (1, 2, 'NP'), (2, 3, 'NP')
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you describe a bit more clearly what it is that you want this code to do?  What does "all different combinations of a nested list" mean? 
 Providing desired output for the given input structure would go a long way towards doing this.  Also, you seem to have some code written already, as you provide output of some kind.  How about showing us that code?  In short, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) explaining your issue.

Comment: i don't understand the algorithm you want to apply here. from your example the input (10 numbers) gets reduced into 6 numbers. how do you get 6? I see `[5,6]` in the output is then either `5` or `6`. but `[2,3,4, [5,6]]` becomes `2,5` or `2,6` or `3,5` or `3,6`, etc... but how is that different from `[[2,3,4], [5,6]]`? if that how it is, you could just go through your nested lists and every time you find one append it to a flat list of lists. single numbers then having a list of one element. and then go from there. but again, I don't understand the problem to begin with.

Comment: the rules seem arbitrary. what is the use case? maybe this is a XY-problem?

Comment: Now it looks like a different question...are you asking how to get the possible outcomes from the nested list?

Comment: If its possible, i prefer to have the last result (all possible trees) from the backpointer. I wrote a recursive function,  but i get all tuples unclassfied. I dont know how to define a list and how to manage the index which is unknown and depends on the next tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works well, without making nested list. Directly retrieve all possible trees from the root.

```
backpointer = {}
rules_prob = {}
syn_tags = []
syn_probs = []

def get_syn_tree(bp, ix):

    if bp[1] - bp[0] == 1:  # end - start = 1   (2, 3, N)
        return

    current_ix = ix
    for i in range(len(backpointer[bp])-1):
        syn_tags.append(syn_tags[current_ix].copy())

    counter = 0
    for item in list(backpointer[bp]):
        # (0, 6, S) -> (4, N,VP) =>     (0, 4, N) , (4, 6, VP)
        syn_tags[current_ix + counter].add((bp[0], item[0], item[1]))
        syn_tags[current_ix + counter].add((item[0], bp[1], item[2]))

        get_syn_tree((bp[0], item[0], item[1]), current_ix + counter)
        get_syn_tree((item[0], bp[1], item[2]), current_ix + counter)

        counter += 1

syn_tags.append({(start, end, A)})
syn_probs.append(0)  # for + = 0, for × = 1
get_syn_tree((start, end, A), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can first write a recursive generator to "un-nest" your nested `list`s. Here's a quick and dirty approach<sup>1</sup>:

```
def unnest(lst, append=False):
    chunk = []
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            if chunk:
                yield chunk
            yield from unnest(x, True)
            chunk = []
        else:
            if append:
                chunk.append(x)
            else:
                yield [x]
    if chunk:
        yield chunk

lst = [0, 1, [2, 3, 4, [5, 6]], 7, [8, 9]]  # per original question
print(list(unnest(lst)))
#[[0], [1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7], [8, 9]]
```

Now use `itertools.product` to get the desired combination of elements:

```
from itertools import product
print(list(product(*unnest(lst))))
#[(0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8),
# (0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 9),
# (0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8),
# (0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 9),
# (0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8),
# (0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9),
# (0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8),
# (0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 9),
# (0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8),
# (0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 9),
# (0, 1, 4, 6, 7, 8),
# (0, 1, 4, 6, 7, 9)]
```

**Notes**:

1. `yield from` only works in python 3